# google cloud endpoints custom auth jwk

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I trying to implement a custom auth with google endpoints.

It work fine until one point, i don't know how i implement the jwk_uri, i'm new to openId.

For testing i have used this site to generate key pairs with the jwks file,
[jwks Generator](https://mkjwk.org/).After searching i think this is a special openIdConnect server, but i'm not sure in the details.

From Endpoints i get the error BAD_SIGANTURE.

Thank you for any explanation.